# useFieldArray not reading data passed in to fields

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am pre-populating data into my array using defaultValues. I am picking this data from a reducer. However, it does not populate it. I can see that valid data is picked by the useSelector but the fields in the fields.map only has an id that looks similar to a uuid (a545sad5d-6576sd5-sdadf). Following is a little snippet

```
const losses = useSelector(state => state.losses);
const { handleSubmit, control, register, errors } = useForm({defaultValues: {
    losses: [losses]
  }});
  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "losses"
  });
{fields.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <div className={style.losses} key={item.id}>
                    <InputText  defaultValue={item.type}  register={register} errors={errors} name={`losses[${index}].type`} />
                    <InputText defaultValue={item.amount} register={register} errors={errors}  name={`losses[${index}].amount`} />
                    <InputText  defaultValue={item.date} register={register} errors={errors} name={`losses[${index}].date`} />
                  </div>
    );
}
```

My losses has the data `[{ id: 45, type: 'accident', amount:'500', date:'2020-05-05'}, { id: 46, type: 'fire', amount:'550', date:'2020-05-04'}]` but while iterating through fields using .map, i get only one item with an id: tyu56rt45r-rt5rt-df4567. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that prior to calling `useSelector` on losses, I was doing a dispatch to `fetchLosses` by using `useEffect()` method of react-hook-form . Found out that the component was not updated. with the new loss values. I need a re-render to update the component

fix:

```
useEffect(() => {
reset(knownLosses)
}[reset, knownLosses]
```

I had to call the `reset` method of `useForm()` to update the form with the newly fetched `knownLosses`

Answer (score 0):

One more crucial point to add, useFieldArray must be called before useEffect hook in the react file, otherwise the fields are populated when you click on the Append button.

```
//correct Order
const {
    fields,
    append,
    remove
} = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name
});

useEffect(()=>{

 --------
//Incorrect order
useEffect(()=>{ ....
useFieldArray({ ...
```